# Eliminating Char from String

Tags: java, string, loops, char

I am trying to eliminate all occurrences of 'X' in the String "cleaned" but I keep getting an outofbound exception. What is wrong with my code? **I NEED to use a while loop and int loc to eliminate the ocurrences**

```
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
     String cleaned = "abcXabcXabc";
     char remove= 'X';
     int loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove);

     System.out.println ("before: "+ cleaned);

     while (loc != -1)
     {
     String part1= cleaned.substring(0, loc); 
     String part2= cleaned.substring(loc+1);
     cleaned = part1+part2;
     }

     System.out.println ("after: " + cleaned);
     }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `replace()`.

Comment: @Satya because I need to use "loc" to eliminate 'X' and the while loop

Comment: `loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove);` is never updated.

Comment: @JavaB: No, you don't - you can just use `cleaned = cleaned.replace("X", "");`

Comment: @Tunaki how can I fix that?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the OP can't use `.replace()`, perhaps he's restricted to loops

Comment: @Tunaki It's probably a assignment, and he is supposed to learn loops

Comment: @JavaB By updating it in the loop?

Comment: It is an assignment, and I am given a while loop and loc. @JonSkeet

Comment: put loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove); inside the loop

Comment: Then you should say so in your question. Any time you've got an unusual constraint (like being unable to use the standard library methods) you should make that clear in the question.

Comment: @RAnders00 yes, it is an assignment

Comment: ok, sorry. I fixed it @JonSkeet

Comment: How is `substring` allowed if you "can't use standard library methods"?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!However, I do not understand how that line of code helps? @wandering-warrior

Comment: @JavaB: Have you tried debugging through the code? Without that line, how do you ever expect the loop to end, apart from anything else? If `loc` isn't -1 the first time you enter the loop, and you don't change it *inside* the loop...

Comment: Yes, I tried but I didn't know how to fix it. That's why I asked this question. @JonSkeet

Comment: Why do you seek lines of code? Why not try mess with the code yourself and see what happens? What do you think changed when you put that line in the loop?

Comment: Because I couldn't figure it out... @wandering-warrior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you were never updating `loc`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String cleaned = "abcXabcXabc";
    char remove = 'X';

    int loc;
    while ((loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove)) != 1)
    {
        String part1 = cleaned.substring(0, loc);
        String part2 = cleaned.substring(loc + 1);
        cleaned = part1 + part2;
    }

    System.out.println("after: " + cleaned);
}
```

The expression used in the `while` statement may be slightly confusing for you, I will try to explain it:

- Outside of the loop a `int loc;` is declared.
- Before every loop it gets the new index of the next `X` assigned.
- By wrapping a assignment into brackets, one can further use what has been assigned. So, the new index is assigned to `loc` on every iteration and then checked for being `-1`.

Of course, if you were actually willing to write something like this in a real application, you would want to use [`String.replace(target, replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String cleaned = "abcXabcXabc";
    // Notice this is now a String
    String remove = "X";

    cleaned = cleaned.replace(remove, "");

    System.out.println("after: " + cleaned);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
     String cleaned = "abcXabcXabc";
     char remove= 'X';
     int loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove);
     int currentPos = 0;
     String result = "";

     System.out.println ("before: "+ cleaned);

     while (loc != -1)
     {
         result = result + cleaned.substring(currentPos,loc);
         currentPos = loc+1;
         loc = cleaned.indexOf(remove, currentPos);
     }

     System.out.println ("after: " + result);
}
```

This should do the job.  You might want to look at StringBuilder class though.